# Find the CDF of a probability class

Tags: probability

[image]

How do I set up this CDF? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Since $F_X(x)=P(X \leqslant x)$ we have:
$$F_X(25)+F_X(26)+F_X(34)=\frac{15+19+25}{128} + \frac{15+19+25}{128} + \frac{15+19+25+33}{128} = \frac{211}{128}$$
$$(211,128)=1 \Longrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{c} p=211 \\ q=128 \end{array}\right\} \Longrightarrow p+q=339$$